# How to plot a histogram in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a histogram with this data.

```
dict_values([2.5039286220812003e-18, 8.701119009863531e-17, 9.181036322384948e-17, 8.972473923736572e-17, 9.160265320730097e-17, 8.826609291023463e-17, 8.888913336226638e-17, 8.993242948900264e-17, 9.556623462346049e-17, 8.847279448923369e-17, 8.86804710730486e-17, 8.806035948033239e-17])
```

This is my code:

```
print(len(new_dictonary.values()))
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.hist(new_dictonary.values())
plt.show()
```

I expect to have 12 bar, but I got only two bars. I  have to use `plt.hist`
[image]

How could correct my code to have the right picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer:** The problem is that your values are very small in magnitude and 11 out of 12 are very close to each other and the remaining one is far away. So to have each value plotted individually as a separate bar, you need a large number of bins. Now if you limit your x-axis to show the 11 similar values out of 12, you will see that having `bins=1000` (a large number) shows 11 bars.

```
plt.hist(new_dictonary, bins=1000, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(0.8e-16, 1e-16)
```

[image]

If you show them all, you will see how far they are. I don't know how you plan to fit a distribution to such data.

```
plt.hist(new_dictonary, bins=1000, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

Comment: I need an histogram. In fact I want to plot distribution curve over this histogram.

Comment: Then you need to specify bins accordingly so as to have 12 bars. Your values are unequally spaced. In fact 11 of them are close and 1 is far away. So you need a large number of bins so that each value appears as a bar

Comment: thank you very much for your help. You put an important  point: how I plan to fit a distribution for such data. In fact, I hope that you can help me in this point. I need to extract the confidential interval for my data. I am not sure what to do exactly. But I feel that  the first thing to do is to analyze my data distribution. but for many cases I found that Theoretical values pdf in my interval is equal to [nan]. so I feel that I am lost. I would be very grateful for your help really